# Make the sails.js server monitor file change using chokidar and then emit socket message

Tags: sockets, sails.js

I use chokidar to monitor if files have been changed in a folder. At the moment it is triggered when a user updates an Experiment Model in my ExperimentController.

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
...
var watcher = chokidar.watch('assets/output-model-files', {ignored: /[\/\\]\./, persistent: true});
watcher.on('change', function(path) {
...read my changed file and update the content of my database, and send a socket publishUpdate message...
... read file content in an asynchronous way
fs.readFile(path,"utf-8", function (err, data) {
... update the experiment object with the content of the changed file
Experiment.update(req.param('id'), ExpObj, function expUpdated(err) {});
... send a message via socket saying that the exeriment object has been updated             
Experiment.publishUpdate(req.param('id'), {name: exp.name,
    results: JSON.stringify(myres),
    action: ('file has just been updated. nb of trajectories: '+totalNbTrajectories)
});
```

But I would like to constantly monitor any change in the target folder and send Experiment.publishUpdate messages when it happens from the moment when the sails.js server starts, and not when a user update an experiment object.
Where could I place that chokidar.watch(...) code on the server side so as to update an experiment object from a file change? socket.js?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found that locating the code in bootstrap.js seems to do the job perfectly reagrding the even triggering...

My bootstrap.js now looks like:

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');
var sys = require('sys');
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {

// It's very important to trigger this callack method when you are finished 
// with the bootstrap!  (otherwise your server will never lift, since it's waiting on the bootstrap)

  User.update({}, {online: false},
    function userUpdated(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            var watcher = chokidar.watch('assets/output-model-files', {ignored: /[\/\\]\./, persistent: true});
            watcher.on('change', function(path) {
                        console.log('File', path, 'has been changed'); 
                        // do file reading and presumably Experiment publish update here
            });
        }

        cb();
    }
  )

};
```